# how to load images from a cfc with parameters used as img src attribute in Coldfusion?

Tags: image, file-upload, coldfusion, amazon-s3

I'm running `Coldfusion8` and a have a page that shows product images. Images can either be pre-stored on `Amazon S3` (prefrerred) or I need to load them from a remote source (specified by the owner), resize, store on S3 and display from there.

While this works "in theory" (images are pulled in, converted and stored), I'm having problems displaying the newly created images, which never works on first load. Once I refresh the page, the images are loading allright.

This is what I'm doing:

1. Inside my display_image.cfc, which constructs the HTML markup:

   ```
    <!--- check media log for availablity through S3 --->
    <cfif results.typ NEQ "img" AND results.typ NEQ "alt">
       <!--- call cfc to pull in and store image to s3 --->
       <cfset variables.imageSrc = "http://www.page.de/test/services/img_handler.cfc" & "?method=upload&cm=upload_search&pt=" & results.bildpfad & "&fl=" & results.bilddateiname & "&se=" & results.iln & "&ar=" & results.artikelnummer & "&ck=" & variables.screenWidth & "&ax=rm&gb=s">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset variables.imgFail = "true">
    </cfif>
   ```
2. Variables being passed

   ```
   method = the method handling uploads  
   cm = routing inside method  
   pt = remote image path  
   fl = remote file name   
   se = seller id  
   ar = item corresponding to this image  
   ck = screen width (to load responsive image size)  
   ax = remote access trigger  
   gb = return images size
   ```
3. Inside my image_handler.cfc

   ```
   <!--- set variables --->
   <cfscript>  
       var LOCAL = {};                 
           LOCAL.command = cm;
           LOCAL.imgPath = pt;
           LOCAL.imgFile = fl;
           LOCAL.sellerILN = se;
           LOCAL.article = ar;
           LOCAL.cookie = LSParseNumber(ck);
           LOCAL.getBack = gb;
           LOCAL.access = ax;
           // routing
           if ( LOCAL.command NEQ "" ) {
                LOCAL.action = LOCAL.command;
           } else {
                LOCAL.action = "upload";
           }
           // s3 misc
           LOCAL.bucketPath = Session.bucketPath;
           LOCAL.bucketName = Session.bucketName;
           LOCAL.acl = "public-read";
           LOCAL.storage = "";
           LOCAL.tempDirectory = expandPath( "../members/img/secure/" );
           LOCAL.allow = "png,jpg,jpeg";
           LOCAL.failedLoads = "";
           LOCAL.altFailedLoads = "";
           LOCAL.createBucket = "false";
           LOCAL.errorCount = 0;
           LOCAL.altErrorCount = 0;
           LOCAL.cacheControl = 1;
           LOCAL.contentType = "image";
           LOCAL.httptimeout = "300";
           LOCAL.cacheDays = "30";
           LOCAL.storageClass = "REDUCED_REDUNDANCY";
           LOCAL.keyName = "";
           LOCAL.baseUrl = "http://www.page.com";
           LOCAL.imageSrc = "";
           LOCAL.testFilePath = LOCAL.imgPath & LOCAL.imgFile;
           LOCAL.fileExt = ListLast(LOCAL.testFilePath, ".");
           // image size indicator
           LOCAL.runner = "s,m,l,xl";
           LOCAL.worked = "true";
       </cfscript> 

       <cftry>
           <!--- get image --->
           <cfhttp timeout="45" throwonerror="no" url="#LOCAL.testFilePath#" method="get"   useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12"  getasbinary="yes" result="objGet">

   <!--- determine which image size to create (depending on screen width) --->
           <cfif LOCAL.cookie LT 320 >
               <cfset LOCAL.runner = "l,s">
           <cfelseif LOCAL.cookie GTE 320 AND LOCAL.cookie LTE 767>
               <cfset LOCAL.runner = "l,m">
           <cfelseif LOCAL.cookie GT 768 AND LOCAL.cookie LTE 1279>
               <cfset LOCAL.runner = "xl,m">
           <cfelseif LOCAL.cookie GT 1280>
               <cfset LOCAL.runner = "xl,l">
           </cfif>

           <!--- validate --->
           <cfif len(objGet.Filecontent) EQ 0 OR objGet.Mimetype EQ "text/html">
               <cfset LOCAL.worked = LOCAL.worked& "false length or mime">
           <cfelseif NOT listfindnocase(LOCAL.allow, LOCAL.fileExt )>
                <cfset LOCAL.worked = LOCAL.worked& "false wrong extension">
           <cfelse>
                <!--- create temp image and resize --->
                <cfset LOCAL.objImage = ImageNew(objGet.FileContent)>
                <cfset LOCAL.basePath = LOCAL.tempDirectory & "_base_" & LOCAL.imgFile>
                <cfset imageWrite( LOCAL.objImage, LOCAL.basePath, ".99")>
                <cfset LOCAL.base = imageRead( LOCAL.basePath )>
                <cfset LOCAL.imageSrc = LOCAL.tempDirectory>
                <cfset ImageSetAntialiasing(LOCAL.base,"on")>
                <cfset variables.loopCount = 0>

                <!--- portrait --->
                <cfif ImageGetWidth( LOCAL.base ) LT ImageGetHeight( LOCAL.base )>
                     <!--- loop through image size, like "xl,m" --->
                     <cfloop list="#LOCAL.runner#" delimiters="," index="letter"><cfset variables.loopCount = variables.loopCount+1>
                         <cfset LOCAL.lt = ListGetAt(LOCAL.runner, variables.loopCount, ",")>
                         <cfset LOCAL.height = Application.strConfig.respH[LOCAL.lt]>
                         <cfset LOCAL.width = "">
                         <cfset ImageScaleToFit(LOCAL.base, LOCAL.width, LOCAL.height, "bilinear")>
                         <cfset LOCAL.filekey = LOCAL.lt & "_" & LOCAL.imgFile>
                         <cfset LOCAL.keyName = LOCAL.sellerILN & "/" & LOCAL.filekey>
                         <cfset LOCAL.filename = LOCAL.tempDirectory & LOCAL.filekey>
                         <cfset imageWrite( LOCAL.base, LOCAL.filename, ".99" )>

                         <!--- call s3 --->
                        <cfset Application.strObjs.s3.putObject(LOCAL.bucketName, LOCAL.filekey, LOCAL.contentType, LOCAL.httptimeout, LOCAL.cacheControl, LOCAL.cacheDays, LOCAL.acl, LOCAL.storageClass, LOCAL.keyName, LOCAL.imageSrc, "false" )>
                        <cfset fileDelete( LOCAL.tempDirectory & LOCAL.lt & "_" & LOCAL.imgFile )>
                    </cfloop>
                    <!--- cleanup --->
                    <cfset fileDelete( LOCAL.tempDirectory & "_base_" & LOCAL.imgFile )>
              </cfif>
              <!--- pass back image THIS DOESN'T WORK --->

              <cfscript>
              // set image path and mime type
                  if ( LOCAL.getBack EQ "s" ){
                      LOCAL.passPath = Session.bucketPath & Session.bucketName & "/" & LOCAL.sellerILN & "/" & ListGetAt(LOCAL.runner, Listlen(LOCAL.runner), ",") & "_" & LOCAL.imgFile;
                  } else if( LOCAL.getBack EQ "l" ) {
                      LOCAL.passPath = Session.bucketPath & Session.bucketName & "/" & LOCAL.sellerILN & "/" & ListGetAt(LOCAL.runner, 1, ",") & "_" & LOCAL.imgFile;
                  }
              if ( LOCAL.fileExt EQ "jpg" ){
                      LOCAL.fileExt = "jpeg";
                  }
              LOCAL.mime = "image/" & LOCAL.fileExt;
              </cfscript>
              <!--- pass back as content --->
              <cfcontent reset="no" type="#LOCAL.mime#" file="#LOCAL.passPath#" />
          <cfreturn />
   ```

Like I said, this runs ok, pulls in, validates and stores images, the smaller one created being passed back as a `cfcontent` element. However, I cannot get it to work = the image is created and stored, but whatever I'm passing back, the image is not displayed until I refresh the page and trigger a new search.

**question:**
Is there something I'm doing wrong in my `iamge_handler`? I think it could be related to my use of `cfcontent` but I>m not sure.

Comment: I think you might be experiencing a race condition. The code is probably taking longer to create the image than it takes for the html to be sent to the browser and the browser to look for the image. try adding  `<cfthread action="sleep" duration="2000"/>` after `<cfset variables.imageSrc = "htt...` to get the page to pause a couple seconds and see if that works without a refresh. If it does, at least we know it's a race condition and can work on fixing that.

Comment: Ok. Good idea. I have tried `sleeping` with 1500ms. Things noticably slow down, but the images still don't show. Must be something else.

Comment: how long would it take for you to get the image to load with a refresh? Like between initial run and final refresh? Can you do the initial load and then refresh quick enough that the image doesn't load when you refresh?

Comment: not sure I understand. Are you saying load the page and refresh right away?

Comment: yeah, just ruling out the possibility of the race condition. If it truly is a race condition, you should be able to take out the sleep and then load and refresh the page quick enough to still have the image not show.

Comment: ok. Forgot to mention, the page content is loaded via Ajax, so I can't really refresh the page.

Comment: Don't forget to var scope 'objGet' and 'letter'

Comment: @duncan - now you have me thinking... how do I scope `letter`? Do I declare it upfront `LOCAL.lette=""` and then use `index="LOCAL.letter"`? Thanks for clarification.

Comment: either that or just `var letter = "";`